# Gitlab Best Practice for having multiple instances of the same codebase

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-7

I have a master codebase of an application that i am working on. I want to duplicate this codebase into 'n' number of instances depending on who buys my codebase. Also from time to time i may have updates to all of the codebases and some additional customized code on each instance. How to achieve this in gitlab? I want to make sure that i can push to all codebases at once without affecting the additional customized code. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "forks" and it is supported by current GitLab.

You create separate forks for your master repo. Pushing or merging changes into the master repo is automatically propagated to forks. On the other hand, each fork maintains it's own changes and can be developed against individually.

Comment: I have problems now.. I am not able to automatically sync my forked project with the master

Answer (score 0):

There is something called Mirror Repository where we can automatically sync forked project with master